# CasperJS - Select dropdown menu without id or class only by value

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am trying to select a dropdown menu only by value (no id or class) using CasperJS

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="select select-large select-block">
<select>
<option value="31110674">Details 1</option>
<option value="1346954">Details 2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would drop into jquery and use evaluate  see http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you want to do with the dropdown menu? Retrieving the textual content or triggering an action? If your question is about the selection itself, you should definitely learn CSS or XPath more thoroughly... ;)